# Is there a way to specify a function's return type as a template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, types, overloading

I have a function template that I'm writing, which deals with a lot of objects of type `N` (which can only be a couple of different things, but there's a lot of logic in this template which I don't want to duplicate in separate functions). In several places in this function, I also have declarations like `auto somevar = SomeFunction(someobject);` where `someobject` is of type `N` and `SomeFunction` is overloaded, returning different types based on the type of `someobject` — but, importantly, no overload of `SomeFunction` returns an `N`. Now, instead of a plain variable, I want to have a container (specifically, `std::unordered_set`) whose elements are of the type returned by `SomeFunction`, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to write the necessary class template parameter.

I've tried `std::unordered_set<auto>` hoping the compiler can deduce the type from what elements it is initialized with, but that didn't work. I tried `std::unordered_set<SomeFunction(someobject)>`, `std::unordered_set<SomeFunction(someobject)::type>`, and `std::unordered_set<typeof(SomeFunction(someobject))>`, but those didn't work either. It seems the C++ standard lacks a way to express this directly.

Comment: Assuming C++11 and later, look up `decltype`.

Comment: Assuming C++17 and later, you might be able to use CTAD, depending on your use case. `std::unordered_set set{ { SomeFunction(someObject) } };`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some others have said, you should use `decltype`. So you'll write `std::unordered_set<decltype(SomeFunction(someobject))>` as your return type.

Sidenote: You might find mention online of `typeof` which the GCC compiler added support for before C++11 added `decltype`. `typeof` works in the same way as `decltype` but isn't part of the C++ standard and so isn't supported by non-GCC compilers. For this reason you should always use `decltype` instead of `typeof`.

Answer (score 0):

What I did is write a class template `some_transform` that can be used like this `std::unordered_set<some_transform<N>::Type>`, where `some_transform` essentially maps the given type `N` to the corresponding return value of `SomeFunction`. The actual mapping is defined in specializations of the template class `some_transform`, so it looks like this:

```cpp
template <typename N> class some_transform
{
public:
    typedef N Type; // this identity mapping is not useful, except so the IDE expects a member type by this name
};
template <> class some_transform<A>
{
public:
    typedef X Type;
};
template <> class some_transform<B>
{
public:
    typedef Y Type;
};
```

Using this class template, `some_transform<A>::Type` resolves to type `X`, and `some_transform<B>::Type` resolves to type `Y`. So the expression `some_transform<N>::Type` can be used in template parameters where a type is expected, within a template with parameter `N`, where the actual type parameter (`X` or `Y`) depends on whether `N` is `A` or `B`. I just have to make sure this class correctly maps the types given to `SomeFunction` (as mentioned in the question) to the corresponding types returned by `SomeFunction`.

Note that the identifier `Type` isn't special, and can by anything; in fact, the `some_transform<N>` class can have multiple member types, *e. g.* `IndexType` and `HashType`; and a name for the class might be better as something like `TypeMap`, where the name of the member type indicates what transformation or mapping is done.

Comment: You vastly over complicated this. Do a search on decltype and declval